# Construct a Brownian Motion with given Covariance matrix next steps?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am looking at some practise questions and stumped on one. Likely just been sat down for too long, but I tried two days in a row and not sure how to proceed.

I was given a Covariance matrix M:
\begin{matrix}
 a^2+b^2 & 0 & 2ab   \\
 0 & 4 & 0  \\
2ab & 0 & a^2+b^2 
\end{matrix}

My tutor in a video stated the below result for M^(1/2) ... is there some method or trick to get there?

\begin{matrix}
 a & 0 & b   \\
 0 & 2 & 0  \\
b & 0 & a 
\end{matrix}

and how would one proceed from here to get the brownian motions? would you simply state a column vector has components of independent Brownian Motions? I have a feeling it's something to do with Spectral Decomposition (M=QDQ^T) but really not sure.

I had a look at [Missing a trick: 3D Brownian Motion from a covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584655/missing-a-trick-3d-brownian-motion-from-a-covariance-matrix) but couldnt follow...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In this case $M^{1/2}$ can be easily guessed and verified. In general,
$M^{1/2}$ can be obtained from diagonalizing $M$:
If $M=QDQ^T$ Then $M^{1/2}=QD^{1/2}Q^T$.

Let $B=(B_1,B_2,B_3)^T$ be standard Brownian motion in three dimensions, that has covariance matrix $E[B(t)B^T(t)]=tI$ at time $t$.
Then $W(t)= M^{1/2} B(T)$ is a Brownian motion with covariance matrix
$$E[W(t)W^T(t)]= M^{1/2} E(B(t) B^T(t))M^{1/2} =M^{1/2} \cdot t \cdot  M^{1/2} =tM \,$$ at time $t$.

Comment: This helps, thank you!