# Is this a convention? Correlated Brownian Motions in SDE

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Sometimes I see the following in certain papers for SDE in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$dX = \mu dt + \sigma dB$$

But they specify $\mathbb{E}[B^i B^j] = D^{ij} \neq \delta^{ij}$ for some symmetric matrix $D$.

I have a suspicion that this is equivalent to the following SDE

$$dX = \mu dt + \sigma D dW$$

Where now $W_t$ is a Brownian motion that does in fact satisfy the usual uncorrelated properties. For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458030/462531) seems to support the interchanging of correlations and just multiplying by a matrix.

Is this correct?

Comment: I would suspect that we need $D$ to be positive-definite rather than just symmetric, and that it should be $dX = \mu dt + \sigma D^{1/2}dW$ instead, but I don't know immediately off the top of my head.

Comment: Make your life simple and consider two Brownian motions. For two uncorrelated BMs $W_1$ and $W_2$ the two processes $B_1=W_1$ and $B_2=\rho W_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W_2$ are obviously two correlated BMs. The converse is however not true. For two correlated BMs $B_1,B_2$ there does not necessarily exist a BM $W_2$ that is uncorrelated with $B_1$. One usually starts with uncorrelated $W_1,W_2$ and constructs the correlated $B_1,B_2$ from those as above.

Comment: @KurtG. Are you sure the converse isn't true?  If $B_1$ and $B_2$ have correlation $\rho$, can't you define $W_2 = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}B_1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}B_2$ to get a BM uncorrelated with $B_1$?

Comment: What makes you think that this linear combination of normals is even normal? There is a standard counter example against the belief that the sum of normals is normal. This  is true in  general *only* when they are uncorrelated.

Comment: @KurtG. Hmm... I'm having trouble seeing why Levy's characterization of Brownian motion doesn't give that $W_2$ is a BM.  I suppose to be precise I should clarify that when I said "$B_1$ and $B_2$ have correlation $\rho$," I meant $d\langle B_1,B_2\rangle_t = \rho dt$ for a deterministic constant $\rho \in (-1,1)$.  With that clarification, $W_2$ is a BM, right?

Comment: @user6247850 . I think you are right. Normal variables have fewer properties than Brownian motions. Thanks for this fruitful discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$B=AW$$
with $A$ a suitable matrix.
If you calculate (using Einstein's summation convention)
$$\mathbb{E}[B_iB_j] = A_{ik}A_{jl}\mathbb{E}[W_k W_l] = A_{ik}A_{jl}\delta_{kl}t = A_{ik}A_{jk}t$$
So it works if you take any matrix $A$ such that $D_{ij}=A_{ik}A_{jk}$.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: does this work when certain fields talk about correlation using quadratic covariation? I.e. $\langle W_i , W_j \rangle = \rho_{ij}t$, and according to Kurt G's comments there appears to be caveats sometimes. What situations can I absorb a matrix and call it a correlated B.M. and what situations can I take a correlated B.M. and make it a matrix times a standard one?